# How to loop through each value in a 3D matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix, 10x10x40, that is storing information of an image through time, where the the rows and columns indicate the spectral value at a specific point, and the third dimension is time. So in other words, a 10x10 image at 40 points in time.  I would like to loop through each row, column and view that pixel history (1,1,:), (1,2,:)....(10,10,:).

Here's what I'm doing now:

```matlab
val = [];
for i = 1:10;
  for j = 1:10;
    for k = 1:length(timevector)
      val(k) = my_matrix(i,j,k); 
    end
  end
end
```

Since I want to iterate through each pixel in time and then save that data, what would be the best way to store the new value/time vectors? I want to end up with 100 pixel history vectors, right now I end with one, and it's because val is written over within the loop. I know it's not advised to create variables within a loop, so what is the best alternative? Should I look into storing the output as a structure? I've been staring at this and I have over-complicated everything.

Comment: It's unclear what your expected output is. You want a 100 element vector output? How should the 10x10 2D "layer" correspond to the 1D array? Do you expect to end up with 100 vectors, each 1x40 in size still containing all the time data? How is this any different to your original matrix?

Comment: I'm eventually going to filter each vector, which I could do in the loop to create a filtered matrix- I just can't figure out how to make/execute the loop

Comment: You can also filter in vectorized form, depending on the filter function. E.g. `filtfilt` operates along the first dimension with more than 1 element, so by permuting the matrix, filtering, and then de-permuting, you will get a huge performance boost compared to looping.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). State what you're trying to achieve, not just how to solve a tiny part of the issue. The best output format will depend on what you're trying to do, and as @rinkert says you may not need this step at all

Comment: Please add a minimal example and the desired output.

Comment: The desired output is a filtered matrix of the same size as my original one. The code sample I included doesn't contain any filter function because I haven't decided on one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the structure you prefer, you can also use matlab's functions `reshape` and `num2cell` to get the output in the following form:

Alternative 1:

```
A = reshape(A,[],10);
```

This will return a matrix (100x40) where each row is a pixel's history.

Alternative 2:

```
A = num2cell( reshape(A,[],40), 2)
```

This will return a cell array (100x1) where each cell contains a vector (40x1) with each pixel's history.

Alternative 3:

```
A = squeeze( num2cell( permute(A, [3,1,2]), 1) );
```

This will return a cell array (10x10) where each cell contains a vector (40x1) with each pixel's history.

Comment: Your welcome! Checking your other questions, I saw you haven't accepted any answers. If you just weren't satisfied with the provided answers until now that's totally okay. However, if you just hadn't noticed how you do it, you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it and it won't appear as unanswered on the board anymore. ( Of course, only accept an answer if it works and answers you question well. )

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want to do with it, you don't need to store them in separate vectors. You can just get one of these pixel history vectors, like so,

```
pixel_history = squeeze(my_matrix(1,1,:));
```

`squeeze` will remove the singleton dimension from the slice, and make it into a 40-by-1 vector, instead of a 1-by-1-by-40 matrix.

To make the time dimension the first matrix dimension, you could also `permute` the matrix,

```
permute(my_matrix, [3 2 1]);
```

This will swap the 3rd and 1st dimensions, making the 1st dimension time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So, looping through each point in the matrix, 
for i=1:10
        for j = 1:10;
               pixel_history = squeeze(my_matrix(i,j,:)); end end ? I'm still ending up with just a single vector.